# How to upload complex artefacts to nexus so I can manually download specific files later?

Tags: jenkins, nexus, artifacts

I am trying to transition from a model where artifacts are published to jenkins and they consist in 20-50 file and directories. But jenkins does allow to download them one by one or the entire of them as a zip file.

I tried to upload a tar.gz to Nexus and hoped that nexus would allow me to download specific files from this archive but this may not be possible or the web UI does not allow you to browse inside them.

What is the proper way of doing this? I still want to be able to download them completely, as a single archive, or file by file.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to upload them as separate files as well as an archive that contains them.